# pandas merging two dataframes based on index and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following two dataframes:

The measurements:

[image: Measurments from a 96 well plate]

And the corresponding sample descriptions:

[image: sample description stored in an excel file]

I managed to get the second dataframe into the following format:

[image: pivoted dataframe]

I would like to add the first dataframe to the second and name it something like 'values'. How can I do that? I tried merge with different options but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

instead of bringing df_1 in the same form as df, I tried the opposite way:

[image]

and viola, merge is working like a charm:

```
df.index.name = 'row'
df_melt=pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars='row',var_name='column')
pd.merge(df1,df_melt,on=['row','column'])
```